# FindControl returns null in MasterPage

Tags: asp.net, nested, master-pages, findcontrol, nested-datalist

I have a `nested` DataList in MasterPage.
I'm trying to Findcontrol,
but it returns `null` for DataList2.

What I tried so far :

```
DataList DataList1 = Page.Master.FindControl("DataListMain") as DataList;

DataList DataList2 = DataList1.FindControl("DataListNested") as DataList;
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I have solved the problem by changing the code and using Web user control rather than doing this on Masterpage.

Answer (score 0):

DataList has items. So you need to locate the nested DataList by index.

```
DataList dl = ((DataList)Master.FindControl("DataListMain")).Items[i].FindControl("DataListNested") as DataList;
```

Note however that the contents of the Master Page are loaded AFTER the contents of the page using that master.

Comment: You use variable i. Could you add the complete code?

Comment: This is the complete code. `i` is just the index number of the item in `DataListMain` holding the nested datalist

Comment: So should I use foreach?

Comment: Depends if you want to access all the nested `DataListNested` or just one. If you want all then loop the items in `DataListMain`.

Comment: `foreach (DataListItem item in ((DataList)Master.FindControl("DataListMain")).Items)`

Comment: I have a single nested datalist and cannot access it.

Comment: each itemtemplate of the parent datalist can have it's own `DataListNested`. Therefore there can be more than one. Hence the index based access.