# How to get the parent Datalist's row ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist, itemdatabound, nested-datalist

I have a nested Datalist.
I'm trying to get the parent Datalist's ID.
To do this I'm using ItemDataBound on parent Datalist. This line gets the parent Datalist object's row ID
but I'm trying to get the table row's ID which is on the table.
How can I do this?

```
protected void DataListMenu_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var innerDL = e.Item.FindControl("DataListSubMenu") as DataList;
        if (innerDL != null)
        {
            string ID = (e.Item.ItemIndex).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want the parent ID (DataListMenu) or the table's row ID (which is e.Item.ItemIndex)? PS did you solve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51635185/findcontrol-returns-null-in-masterpage

Comment: I'm trying to get the table's row ID. But sorry for the English: I mean, the question's code is wrong for me.

Comment: The row ID is `e.Item.ItemIndex`.

Comment: But I'm searching the other.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean by other. You want the ID of the nested DataList then?

Comment: No I'm trying to get the ID which is on the table

Comment: `DataList parent = sender as DataList;` and then `parent.ID`?

Comment: I have solved this problem by doing this :

I have added a Label to parent datalist. 
Made Eval and store ID on it (main ID).
Then did findcontrol and get its ID
in the question's method.